# I can't use Entity Class (JPA) in Netbeans7.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, netbeans7.0

I tried to use Entity Class (JPA) in Netbeans7.0 but It doesn't work.

1. I create Enterprise Application name **BookApp**.

Create Entity Class

1. I right click at BookApp-ejb and select **Entity Classes fron Database**.
2. In dialog New Entity Class from Database I insert **JNDI Name:jdbc/test** for connect to test database and select table books. After that ,I click Next for insert **Package: entity** and click Finish.

Create Session Bean

1. I right click at BookApp-ejb and select **Session Beans for Entity Classes** and click Next.
2. I click Add All >> and click Next.
3. I insert **Package: sb** , **create Interface:Local** and click Finish.

Create Web Application

1. I right click BookApp-war and select HTML insert **HTML File Name :findBook** and click Finish.
2. I put this code in HTML file

> ```
> <form action="ShowBook" method="POST">
> <h2>Search Book from ISBN </h2>
> Enter ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn" value="" />
> <input type="submit" value="Find" />
> </form>
> ```

1. I right click BookApp-war and select **Servlet** insert **File Name: ShowBook**, **Package: servlets** and click Finish.
2. I right click in editor and select **Insert Code… > Call Enterprise Bean…**
3. In dialog Call Enterprise Bean I select **BooksFacade** and click OK.
4. I uncomment html and insert this code between out.println("");

> ```
> String isbn = request.getParameter("isbn");
> Books book = booksFacade.find(isbn);
> out.println("Title: " + book.getTitle()+ "<BR>");
> out.println("Author: " + book.getAuthor() + "<BR>");
> out.println("Price: " + book.getPrice() + "<BR>");
> ```

1. I clean and build BookApp.
2. I run BookApp.
3. I go to this URL http://localhost:8080/BookApp-war/findBook.html and insert isbn from books table but when I click Find button It show error like this.

> ```
> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that
> ```
>
> prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> ```
> exception
>
> javax.ejb.EJBException
> ```

I don't know what I mistake. I delete Session Beans and create Session beans again but no create Interface. when I run BookApp it show same error. I'm new for EJB. please help me.

---

I'm not sure where is error but this code appear in server log while I build EJB Project.

```
INFO: file:/C:/Users/Mc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BookApp/dist/gfdeploy/BookApp/BookApp-ejb_jar/_BookApp-ejbPU logout successful
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: Error creating temporary file transfer folder
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.createTempFolder(PayloadFilesManager.java:718)
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.createTempFolder(PayloadFilesManager.java:727)
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.access$100(PayloadFilesManager.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager$Temp.<init>(PayloadFilesManager.java:303)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$UploadedFilesManager.extractFiles(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1413)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$UploadedFilesManager.<init>(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$UploadedFilesManager.<init>(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1372)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unknown error creating directory C:\Users\Mc\.netbeans\7.0\config\GF3\domain1\applications\xfer-5751472689020834694
    at org.glassfish.admin.payload.PayloadFilesManager.createTempFolder(PayloadFilesManager.java:709)
    ... 29 more
```

And this code appear in server log after I click Find button in HTML for call ShowBook servlet.

```
INFO: entity.Books actually got transformed
INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB BooksFacade : [java:global/BookApp/BookApp-ejb/BooksFacade, java:global/BookApp/BookApp-ejb/BooksFacade!sb.BooksFacadeLocal]
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [BookApp#BookApp-war.war] at [BookApp-war]
INFO: BookApp was successfully deployed in 7,063 milliseconds.
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913
INFO: file:/C:/Users/Mc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BookApp/dist/gfdeploy/BookApp/BookApp-ejb_jar/_BookApp-ejbPU login successful
WARNING: A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB BooksFacade method public entity.Books sb.BooksFacade.find(java.lang.Object)
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5194)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5092)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4880)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy203.find(Unknown Source)
    at servlets.ShowBook.processRequest(ShowBook.java:46)
    at servlets.ShowBook.doPost(ShowBook.java:79)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have provided an instance of an incorrect PK class for this find operation.  Class expected : class java.lang.Integer, Class received : class java.lang.String.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:498)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:320)
    at sb.AbstractFacade.find(AbstractFacade.java:36)
    at sb.BooksFacade.find(BooksFacade.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5367)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:862)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:371)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5339)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5327)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 31 more

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[ShowBook]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ShowBook threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5194)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5092)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4880)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy203.find(Unknown Source)
    at servlets.ShowBook.processRequest(ShowBook.java:46)
    at servlets.ShowBook.doPost(ShowBook.java:79)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have provided an instance of an incorrect PK class for this find operation.  Class expected : class java.lang.Integer, Class received : class java.lang.String.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:498)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:320)
    at sb.AbstractFacade.find(AbstractFacade.java:36)
    at sb.BooksFacade.find(BooksFacade.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5367)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:862)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:801)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:371)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5339)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5327)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: DId you try starting the webapp without EJBs, does this work?

Comment: The Glassfish log file will give you more information on the error than the message displayed in browser. Check the logs.

Comment: You would have to find out what exactly happened by looking into the stack trace of the exception, look into your server logs to find out and post it here, otherwise it would be really difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The entity manager don't like your String parameter.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have provided an
instance of an incorrect PK class for this find operation.  Class
expected : class java.lang.Integer, Class received : class
java.lang.String.
```

The find method of the entity manager search for a entity with the given id or from the db view with the given PK. I think you have a Book entity like this:

```
@Entity    
public class Book {

   @Id
   private Integer isbn;


....
```

So you have to pass a Integer to the find method.

```
em.find(Integer.parseInt(isbn)) //just a hack
```

I hope that helps you.